# Inheritance construcor

Tags: c++

I tried to make a constructor of derieved class. I've got one error which I can't understand. I mean I've a derieved class which constructor looks like: **header file**

```
Person(string surname_, string name_, int day_, int mounth_, int year_) :date(day_, mounth_, year_);
```

And **.cpp**

```
Person::Person(string surname_, string name_, int day_, int mounth_, int year_):date(day_, mounth_, year_){
    this->surname = surname_;
    this->name = name_;
};
```

And here is an error in the header file right after ":date(day_, mounth_, year_)":

```
    expected a '{'
```

Is it possible to create a body of the constructor in the .cpp file?

Comment: You should be able to, I think the issue is the `:date(day_, mounth_, year_);` in the header. It thinks you are declaring the constructor in the header.

Comment: Looks like the declaration of the `Person` constructor should be `Person(string surname_, string name_, int day_, int mounth_, int year_) : public date;`, but this is far from a [mre].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *declaration* of the constructor must end with a `;` right where you put the `:`. The part that begins with `:` belongs in the *definition* only.

Comment: So it should be in the cpp file? Was it an mistake to put It to the header?

Comment: Yes, it should be in the cpp file. It should not be in the header. The `:date(day_, mounth_, year_)` is part of the definition, along with `this->surname = surname_;` and `this->name = name_;`.